# Prompting an OnEdit dialog to confirm an action

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialog

I have a good spreadsheets function that will copy paste as values a line of data to another spreadsheet when a user ticks with an X a cell. This worked well. However, I recently added a dialog to confirm the action to prevent inadvertent use. However, for some reason my code is not even executing.

I therefore wonder if there is some faulty logic in my code or if it's a restriction of OnEdit function. Your feedback is of utmost value to me. Thanks.

```
function CopyPaste(e) {
    var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var CIP = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12y5scoiksxow09DkW4bXH2YMQLCp_KHBfNFoju3IezA'); //target spreadsheet
    var channels = [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 55, 56, 57, 58]; //Columns to check where the X was ticked
    var ind = channels.indexOf(e.range.columnStart);//Change column numbers to index 
  if (activeSheet.getName() !== 'HL' && activeSheet.getName() !== 'HA' && activeSheet.getName() !== 'AU' || ind == -1 || e.value !== 'X') {

  function showAlert() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    }  
  }

if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".

    return;
    var target = CIP.getSheetByName('Suggestions'); //Makes the output sheet = t
    var lr = target.getLastRow() < 4 ? 4 : target.getLastRow() + 1; //Should it start on Row 4 or on the last row
    Logger.log(lr); // Log road
    var RequiredData = activeSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, activeSheet.getLastColumn())
        .getValues()[0]     
        Logger.log(RequiredData);
        target.getRange(lr, 1, 1, RequiredData.length).setValues([RequiredData])
        Logger.log('done');
    ui.alert('Confirmation received.');

  } else {
    ui.alert('Permission denied.');  
  } 
}
```